# ¿Cómo podría modificar el siguiente código de un vector ascendentemente en c++?

Tags: c++

Buenas noches les presento la siguiente parte de código donde quiero poner una restricción(agregar solamente números que sean ascendentes) en c++(vector)
*A continuación les dejo el código:

```
int i=0,j=0,a=0,n,ar[20],opcion,pos,ban,ant,b=0;
char resp;

cout<<"************MENU*************"<<endl;
cout<<"1.Insertar un elemento"<<endl;
cout<<"ingrese el número de terminos del vector"<<endl;
cin>>n;         
                    
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cout<<"Ingrese el número"<<endl;
    cin>>ar[i];
    for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        if(ar[i]<ar[j])
        {
            a=ar[i];
            a=0;                
        }
    }
}
```

es una parte de código de ordenamiento de menor a mayor sin embargo con anda la restricción desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te has complicado demasiado.

Si solo quieres admitir números ascendentes, no es necesario que compruebes **todos** los valores del vector. Te basta con comprobar **el último**:

```
cout << "************MENU*************" << endl;
cout << "1.Insertar un elemento" << endl;
cout << "ingrese el número de terminos del vector" << endl;
cin >> n;
                
for( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
    cout << "Ingrese el número" << endl;
    int nuevoNumero;
    cin >> nuevoNumero;

    while( i && ( nuevoNumero <= ar[i - 1] ) ) {
        cout << "Numero no valido. Ha de ser mayor que " << ar[i - 1] << '\n';
        cin >> nuevoNumero;
    }

    ar[i] = nuevoNumero;
}
```

Solo se ha de tener en cuenta que, si es el primer número ingresado, no hay que comprobar nada. Lo guardamos en el *arreglo* directamente.

<sub>Por cierto, los índices de *arreglos* empiezan **por `0`**. En tu `for( )`, empezabas en el `1`.</sub>